# Score system based on time NAN

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I've created a score system in my flash Quiz game where the faster you answer a question, the more points you get. At the moment however my tracer shows 'NAN' when I run my game. Can anybody see why this is?

```
var score:int = 0;
var count:int = 0;
var mTimer:Timer;
mTimer = new Timer(100, 70);

function processScore():void {   
    var count:int = mTimer.currentCount;
    var score:int = score +  (700 - (count * 10));
    trace("score registered");
}

trace(aUserAnswers[numLoops] + " " + returnedNumber);
if(aUserAnswers[numLoops] == returnedNumber){
    processScore();
}
```

`returnedNumber` is when a button is clicked, if the number matches that which is in the array, the question is correct.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You're redeclaring `count` and `score` inside `processScore()`. That makes them local variables to the function, unrelated to the previous declared variables of the same name. This means that their values are lost when the function finishes and the previous variables are unchanged. I'm guessing that at some point you divide something by one of them and since you'll always be dividing by zero you get `NAN`.